# How to crop a live video feed in PyQt5? QImage looks sheared

Tags: python, numpy, qt, pyqt5

I have a PyQt5 GUI application. I read a frame from the camera to select a smaller area on it, and later I would like to display only that area. I correctly select the area, and store it in a QRect. But when I try to crop the frames to display and to process later, the displayed live video just sometimes works correctly. but most of the times it looks like on this picture. It becomes slanted, the right corner should be the left corner. And the pink circle should be in the middle of the video, so it is kinda wrong.

[image: Image example]

I have this Worker1 class, where I process the displayed frames.

```
class Worker1(QThread):
    ImageUpdate = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, canvas, selection):
        super().__init__()
        self.ThreadActive = True
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.anim = None
        self.selection = selection

    def run(self):
        Capture = cv.VideoCapture(0)

        old_closest_contour = None
        d_tresh = 300
        P_color = (0, 255, 0)
        global i
        i = 0

        while self.ThreadActive:
            i += 1
            ret, frame = Capture.read()
            if ret:
                if self.selection is None or self.selection.isEmpty():
                    cropped_frame = frame
                else:
                    a = int(self.selection.x())
                    b = int(self.selection.y())
                    width = int(self.selection.width())
                    height = int(self.selection.height())
                    #print(str(a) + " " + str(b) + " " + str(width) + " " + str(height))
                    cropped_frame = frame[b: b + height, a: a + width].copy()
                    #print(cropped_frame.shape[1])
                    #print(cropped_frame.shape[0])

                ### other processing lines, those are not relevant in the displaying ###

                Image = cv.cvtColor(cropped_frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                img = cv.medianBlur(Image, 25)

                cv.circle(img, (x, y), r, P_color, 1)
                cv.circle(img, (x, y), 4, P_color, -1)
                cv.circle(img, point, 0, (255, 0, 255), 10)

                ConvertToQtFormat = QImage(img.data, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
                self.ImageUpdate.emit(ConvertToQtFormat)

        Capture.release()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to set `bytesPerLine` argument.
Replace `ConvertToQtFormat = QImage(img.data, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)` with:

```
ConvertToQtFormat = QImage(img.data, img.shape[1], img.shape[0], img.strides[0], QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

---

`img.strides[0]` applies the number of bytes in each line of `img`.
When `img.shape[1] = 100`, `img.strides[0]` is usually equal `100*3` = `300` bytes when there are 3 bytes per pixel.

The reason that we have the `strides` is that there are cases when lines are not continuous in memory, and the stride doesn't equal width * 3.

The equivalent parameter in `QImage` object is `bytesPerLine`.
By default, QImage object assumes that `bytesPerLine` is a **multiple of 4**.
In case width*3 is not a multiple of 4, padding bytes are assumed to be present at the end of each line.
For example, when width = 101, `bytesPerLine` is 304 instead of 303 (1 padding byte is assumed).
(The multiple of 4 assumption is originated from the [BMP image format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format)).

In our case:

- When `img.shape[1]` is a multiple of 4, the image is going to look correct.
- When `img.shape[1]` is a not multiple of 4, the image is going to be "slanted".
  In our case the NumPy array has no padding bytes, and there is a mismatch between Qt `bytesPerLine` and NumPy `strides`.

---

The solution is setting the `bytesPerLine` parameter (using an overloaded `QImage` constructor).
In general, when converting from NumPy to QImage, we should set `img.strides[0]` as `bytesPerLine` argument.

Comment: Thank you so much. This one parameter solved the issue. And you gave me a good explanation to understand what was the problem.